# Why does CreateWindow in 64-bit Visual Studio C destroy itself on creation?

Tags: c, visual-studio, winapi

I have some example code that simply puts a window on the screen in Windows 10. The program runs fine under 32 bit: the window call back procedure gets sent messages in the creation of the window.

Under 32-bit, the first three messages are:

```
WM_GETMINMAXINFO
WM_NCCREATE
WM_NCCALCSIZE
```

and it proceeds from there until the window is built.

However, under 64-bit, this does not happen; instead, these are the messages sent:

```
WM_GETMINMAXINFO
WM_NCCREATE
WM_NCDESTROY
```

As you can see, right after the window is created, the OS sends a message to destroy it!

Here's the actual code:

```c
/*****************************************************************************/
/*      This sample demonstrates how to continuously acquire pictures        */
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define _NIWIN 

#define PB_QUIT     101       /* id for quit application push button */

// Window proc
LRESULT CALLBACK ImaqSmplProc(HWND hWnd, UINT iMessage, UINT wParam, LONG lParam);

// windows GUI globals
static HINSTANCE    hInst;
static HWND         ImaqSmplHwnd;
static HWND         HStop, HGrab, HQuit, HIntfName, HFrameRate;


static long        CanvasWidth = 512;  // width of the display area
static long        CanvasHeight = 384; // height of the display area
static long        CanvasTop = 10;     // top of the display area
static long        CanvasLeft = 10;    // left of the display area
static long        AcqWinWidth;
static long        AcqWinHeight;

int WINAPI WinMain (HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                       LPSTR lpszCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    CHAR        ImaqSmplClassName[] = "Imaq Sample";
    WNDCLASS    ImaqSmplClass;
    MSG         msg;
   

    // register the main window
    hInst = hInstance;
    if (!hPrevInstance)
    {
        ImaqSmplClass.style         = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
        ImaqSmplClass.lpfnWndProc   = (WNDPROC) ImaqSmplProc;
        ImaqSmplClass.cbClsExtra    = 0;
        ImaqSmplClass.cbWndExtra    = 0;
        ImaqSmplClass.hInstance     = hInstance;
        ImaqSmplClass.hIcon         = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
        ImaqSmplClass.hCursor       = LoadCursor (NULL, IDC_ARROW);
        ImaqSmplClass.hbrBackground = GetStockObject(LTGRAY_BRUSH);
        ImaqSmplClass.lpszMenuName  = 0;
        ImaqSmplClass.lpszClassName = ImaqSmplClassName;
    
        if (!RegisterClass (&ImaqSmplClass))
            return (0);
    }

    // creates the main window
    ImaqSmplHwnd = CreateWindow(ImaqSmplClassName, "LLGrab", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE,
                            CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 680, 440, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    // creates the quit application button
    if (!(HQuit = CreateWindow("Button","Quit",BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
                                550,152,80,40,ImaqSmplHwnd,(HMENU)PB_QUIT,hInstance,NULL)))
      return(FALSE);
    
    // Display the main window
    ShowWindow(ImaqSmplHwnd, SW_SHOW);
    UpdateWindow(ImaqSmplHwnd);
        
    while (GetMessage (&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage (&msg) ;
        DispatchMessage (&msg) ;
    }

    return (int)(msg.wParam);
}

// Message proc
LRESULT CALLBACK ImaqSmplProc(HWND hWnd, UINT iMessage, UINT wParam, LONG lParam)
{
    WORD            wmId;   
    LRESULT theResult;
    
    switch (iMessage)
    {
        case WM_COMMAND:
            wmId    = LOWORD(wParam);
            switch (wmId)
            {
                case PB_QUIT:
                    PostQuitMessage(0);
                    break;
            }
            break;
        case WM_NCDESTROY:
            break;
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);

        default:
            theResult = DefWindowProc(hWnd, iMessage, wParam, lParam);
            return theResult;
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `UINT wParam, LONG lParam` this is wrong for x64

Comment: That part of the code when the compiler told you that the window proc had the wrong signature, and you used a cast to tell it you knew better? Well, it knew better.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `ImaqSmplProc()` window procedure is declared incorrectly, causing you to pass bad data to `DefWindowProc()`.

For `WM_NCCREATE`, the `lParam` holds a pointer, which you are truncating under 64bit to a 32bit value, so `DefWindowProc()` fails to process `WM_NCCREATE` correctly, which then causes `CreateWindow()` to destroy the window.  If you debug the code, you will likely see `DefWindowProc()` returning `FALSE` when processing `WM_NCCREATE` with a bad `lParam` value.

> If an application processes this message, it should return TRUE to continue creation of the window. **If the application returns FALSE, the CreateWindow or CreateWindowEx function will return a NULL handle.**

To fix this, the `wParam` and `lParam` parameters MUST be declared as `WPARAM` and `LPARAM`, respectively:

```cpp
LRESULT CALLBACK ImaqSmplProc(HWND hWnd, UINT iMessage, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
```

This matches the actual signature of [`WNDPROC`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms633573(v=vs.85)):

```cpp
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(
  _In_ HWND   hwnd,
  _In_ UINT   uMsg,
  _In_ WPARAM wParam,
  _In_ LPARAM lParam
);
```

`WPARAM` and `LPARAM` are declared as `UINT_PTR` and `LONG_PTR`, respectively.  Which means they are pointer-sized integers, and so have different sizes under 32bit and 64bit.  Whereas `UINT` and `LONG` have the same size on both 32bit and 64bit.  See [Windows Data Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/windows-data-types). Your original code is not accounting for this difference.

You used a type-cast to silence the compiler from alerting you to your incorrect declaration.  You need to get rid of the type-cast when assigning `ImaqSmplProc` to `ImaqSmplClass.lpfnWndProc`:

```cpp
ImaqSmplClass.lpfnWndProc   = ImaqSmplProc;
```

Any time you find yourself using a type-cast, question yourself as to why, you may be doing something wrong.  Don't use a type-cast unless you *absolutely* need it.  Don't use a type-cast just to keep the compiler silent, it complains about questionable/erroneous things for a reason.

Comment: You don't need the cast ***or*** the `&` operator when assigning the `lpfnWndProc` member (but neither will do any harm,I think). EDIT: OK, your point about using casts is a good one!

Comment: Yes, the `&` is optional, but the type-cast is actually very harmful, as demonstrated by the OP's issue. It stopped the compiler from complaining that the signature of `ImaqSmplProc()` did not match what `lpfnWndProc` was expecting.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is in the types you have specified for the `wParam` and `lParam` arguments to your `ImaqSmplProc` function. These should be of types `WPARAM` and `LPARAM`, respectively.

Why? These are defined as `UINT_PTR` and `LONG_PTR` types - which are **64-bit** integers on x64 builds; thus, your specified `UINT` and `LONG` types are the wrong sizes, so you have undefined behaviour (at best).

Change the definition/declaration to:

```c
LRESULT CALLBACK ImaqSmplProc(HWND hWnd, UINT iMessage, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
```